# Use exponent notation in R

Tags: r, numbers

There is a table which looks roughly like:

```
 V1
1  3.392134e-07
2  3.317284e-07
3  3.398608e-07
4  3.272904e-07
5  3.468952e-07
6  3.212954e-07
```

in **R**. I read it in from a file with read.table and it is a data frame. The table is called `u`. but `mean(u[,1])` does not work with the error:

> In mean.default(u) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

Also converting into numeric did not really solve the problem. Can **R** recognise this notation or is there some way to convert?

So `str(u)` is

```
> str(u)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: num  3.39e-07 3.32e-07 3.40e-07 3.27e-07 3.47e-07 ...
```

and

```
u[is.na(as.numeric(u[,1])), 1]
```

is

```
numeric(0)
```

Comment: R can deal with this notation just fine. In fact, it uses it. You have probably entries different from this in your file. Check `u[is.na(as.numeric(u[,1])), 1]`.

Comment: @Hein I tried using the info provided `mean(u[,1])[1] 3.343806e-07` on `R 3.1.1`

Comment: if there is NA, do `mean(u[,1], na.rm=T)`

Comment: @Hein It seems strange.

Comment: @Hein Are you sure you used `mean(u[,1])` and not `mean(u)`

Answer (score 1):

Reading the provided warning message carefully, I see `mean.default(u)` and I can reproduce the problem like this:

```
u <- read.table(text=" V1
1  3.392134e-07
2  3.317284e-07
3  3.398608e-07
4  3.272904e-07
5  3.468952e-07
6  3.212954e-07", header=TRUE)

mean(u)
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#  In mean.default(u) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Contrary to what you are telling us you are trying to pass the whole data.frame to `mean`. Make sure to pass only one column:

```
mean(u[,1])
#[1] 3.343806e-07
```

Comment: if u is a vector, you could do `mean(u)`. But if u is a data frame, you could either use column index `mean(u[,1])` or use column name `mean(u$V1)`. You'll get the same result.